# python pandas search string in a column and get initial position if the string is found

Tags: python, pandas, string, pattern-matching

Given the following df:

```
data = {'Description':  ['with chicken', 'champagne', 'Chicken', 'bananas and chicken', 'fafsa Lemons', 'GIN CHICKEN'],}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df)
```

if I search on the column of a word, in this case "chicken", I would like to find the initial position in the string if present, here the expected output:

```
data = {'Description':  ['with chicken', 'champagne', 'chicken', 'bananas and chicken','fafsa Lemons', 'GIN CHICKEN'],
       'ChickenPosition':  ['6', 'NA', '1', '13', 'NA', '5']
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df)
```

anybody able to write something extremely  compact without many steps? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
string_to_search = "chicken"

df['ChickenPosition'] = df['Description'].apply(lambda x: x.lower().index(string_to_search.lower()) +1 if string_to_search.lower() in x.lower() else "NA")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
           Description ChickenPosition
0         with chicken               6
1            champagne              NA
2              Chicken               1
3  bananas and chicken              13
4         fafsa Lemons              NA
5          GIN CHICKEN               5
```

+1 here is to have the same result as you requested, otherwise it would be the string index which starts the count from 0

Alternative solution using [pd.Series.str.find](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.find.html):

```
string_to_search = "chicken"

df['ChickenPosition'] = df['Description'].apply(str.lower).str.find(string_to_search.lower()).replace(-1, "NA")
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be shorthand version...

```
import pandas as pd
import re
data = {'Description':  ['with chicken', 'champagne', 'Chicken', 'bananas and chicken', 'fafsa Lemons', 'GIN CHICKEN'],}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

pattern = re.compile('chicken')

results = df['Description'].apply(lambda x: pattern.search(str(x).lower()).span()[0] \
                                  if (pattern.search(str(x).lower()) != None) else 'NA')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```py
df["ChickenPosition"] = np.where(
    (p := df["Description"].str.lower().str.find("chicken")) < 0,
    'NA',
    p + 1,
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
           Description ChickenPosition
0         with chicken               6
1            champagne              NA
2              Chicken               1
3  bananas and chicken              13
4         fafsa Lemons              NA
5          GIN CHICKEN               5
```